# return data to calling activity from searchable

Tags: android, searchview, start-activity

I have this app where the user reads articles through a webview. He can read related articles and press the back or up button to go back through his history. Is there a way to override the search widget in the action bar so that it calls SearchResultsActivity through startActivityForResult() or something? I'd like for the user to click an article and have the link to that article passed back to the webview to keep the history intact.

from ArticleActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_article, menu);

    /* Search results in new activity, clicked article passed back to articleActivity
       Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView */
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();

    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, SearchResultsActivity.class);
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));

    return true;
}
```

from manifest

```
<activity
        android:name=".ArticleActivity"
        android:label="@string/article"
        android:parentActivityName=".CategoryActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="app.morningsignout.com.morningsignoff.CategoryActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

menu_article.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="app.morningsignout.com.morningsignoff.ArticleActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: You mean Search widget in webview? Please post some code

Comment: sorry, I mean the search widget in the actionbar